# How to check if a word is present in a substring of a string using java Regex

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a list of strings of the format "The Url is http://m.gap.com/division.html?dn=gd5646"
The output for the program is a list of urls with the word **product** in it.
I have managed to obtain the urls using regex in java but I dont understand how to check if the word **product** is also present.

Answer (score 0):

If they are all String objects, it is easy to just call `.contains("product")` on the strings. It will return a boolean based on if "product" is present.

[String.contains() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Note: If regex is required, try [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)). It can be called by `myStr.matches(regex)`. If all you need is "product", I believe the regex is `/product/`.

Comment: I need it to do it using regex :/ but .contains is certainly a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem when using `contains("product")` is that it will check for the word in the **whole String**.

You can use the following Regex to find the word only in the *url* substring.

`The Url is https?:\/\/(.*product.*)`

Alternatively, if the word `Product` may be capitalized, you can try:

`The Url is https?:\/\/(.*(P|p)roduct.*)`

You can test the string using the following String method:

`String.matches(regex)`

====================================

Example:

```
if(text.matches("The Url is https?:\/\/(.*product.*)")) {
     //Do Something...
}
```